# Enable CORS in access token url - SPRING

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I am making a simple spring security project. I used Angular for front-end. For authentication i am calling access token from backend but there in no any CORS enable in spring. How can i enable CORS. This is code to get access token

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" 
          authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                       after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML configuration to enable CORS is,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <mvc:cors>

    <mvc:mapping path="/api/**" allowed-origins="http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com"
                 allowed-methods="GET, PUT" allowed-headers="header1, header2, header3"
                 exposed-headers="header1, header2" allow-credentials="false" max-age="123" />

    <mvc:mapping path="/resources/**" allowed-origins="http://domain1.com" />

  </mvc:cors>

 </beans>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding header1,header2,header3 inside allowed-header

Comment: That will be optional in this scenario just add allowed-origins and allowed-methods param

Comment: that works for me but except one url from where i am getting a access token . I made a xml configuration to get a access token and the url to get access token is `http://localhost:8080/life-style/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=nishandhungana41sdfgh&password=nishandhungana`
How can i enable CORS on that URL i tried every possible solution but cann't .. please help me out

Comment: try to use **allowed-headers="Access-Control-Request-Headers"**

Comment: or you can Switch to using Spring's CorsConfigurationSource.See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#cors for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know how to do it via XML, but in my annotation-based configuration CORS is enabled like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;    

@Configuration
public class WebApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedMethods(
                        HttpMethod.GET.name(),
                        HttpMethod.POST.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
                        HttpMethod.PATCH.name(),
                        HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
                        HttpMethod.DELETE.name()
               );
    }
}
```